# Is there a teshuva which speaks about whether Jean pants are Chok Akum?

Tags: halacha, clothing, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, hukot-hagoyim

I was told by someone that there is a Teshuva by the  [Seridei Eish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Yaakov_Weinberg) where there is a discussion of weather wearing denim jeans falls under the category of Chok Akum.

**My question:**

1) Does this Teshuva actually exist? (I'm very interested in seeing it if it does.)

2) If it doesn't, are there any Teshuvos out by him or other poskim of a similar matter?

**Note:** *this is a serious question. Really.*